# android caching web service data

Tags: java, android, web-services, caching, mobile

I'd like to make my Android app responsive, even when the network connection is not.

For certain calls, the data doesn't change that often, so I'd like to be able to retrieve the most recent XML response for a given call.

Ideally, I'd like to do this similar to how web caching works, hash the call/params, set rules as to expiry, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just save the received xml locally and then read that file when there's no internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

Check this session out, it has some interesting info on this topic http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html

Tho he doesn't speak about cache expiration, but it's a good start.

**Edit:**

As pointed out, the link above is not working anymore, here are the updated links:

[Slides](https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-developing-RESTful-android-apps.pdf)

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)

Though this content is a few years old, so I'd recommend looking around for more recent material on this subject as well.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer.

Comment: BTW which is a better approach saving in database or caching

Comment: I guess that heavily depends on your use case :) E.g. How important it is for you to persist your downloaded data across application startups? How expensive it is to re-download the data? Is the data likely to be used offline? Etc.

Comment: its just to show something instead of a progress bar